What is the meaning and background of やうな
私は童話でも書くやうな、または刺繍でも見るやうな気持で. I assume that the meaning of the YAUNA is a combination of YA to repeat and NA to make it negative, but what does the U mean? Can anybody help?

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38256/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/101333/9831


The やう is simply the old spelling of よう(様), used before the war.　In any dictionary, the old kana spelling is listed alongside the modern spelling, such as 思{おも}う[おもふ], 快楽{かいらく}[くわいらく], 醤油{しょうゆ}[しゃうゆ].

私は童話でも書くような、または刺繍でも見るような気持で


I am feeling like writing fairytales or watching embroideries.

More to read: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/歴史的仮名遣

Thank you very much for your clear explanation!
